# Update Google Application ID from a new project in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I've just created a new project but entered the wrong google app engine application id in the **Create New Project dialog box** But now I can't find how to change it without having to recreate a new project.

I've check under File - Settings - Google App Engine and I can only update how I sign in.

How can I edit the Application ID in PyCharm.

Answer (score 0):

I did it manually from the app.yaml file